# Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling, return-value

I have 3 javascript functions:

`validateClk()`, `validateAmPm()` and `getClks()`

And on two occurring events, they get executed as follows:

`OnChange` - executes `validateClk()` and `validateAmPm()`

`OnClick`  - executes `getClks()` (`getClks()` returns a boolean value)

All 3 functions run correctly, but the problem is, after `getClks()` has finished execution and returns a boolean, the next function `postClocks()` doesn't run. I'm very sure that the code for `postClocks()` is correct as well. If I don't use the return statement for `getClks()` then the `getClks()` function doesn't work as expected.

Please help :(

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function validateClk() {
        ....
        var clks = clocks.value;
        if (clks == "") {
            alert('Enter time');
        }
        else { ... }
    }
</script>

<script type='...'>
    function validateAMPM() {
        ...
        var ampm= ap.value;
        if  (ampm=="") {
            alert('Enter am or pm');
        }
    }
</script>

<script type='text/...'>
    function getClks() {
        var clks= clock.value;
        var ampm= ap.value;
        if (clks==" && ampm="") {
            alert('Enter time and am/pm');
            return false;
        }
        else { ... }
        return true;
    }
</script>

<... onChange="validateClk(); validateAmPm();" />

<... button label="Submit" onClick="return getClks(); postClocks(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have all of your custom functions return `boolean` then change the `onclick` event to this:

```
onClick="if(!getClks() || !postClocks()) return false;"
```

assuming you don't want to continue if invalid

Answer (score 4):

It's because you explicitly coded a `return` in there.

```
return getClks();
postClocks();
return false;
```

That code will always just exit after that first `return` statement.  I suggest removing it.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
onClick="return getClks(); postClocks(); return false;"
```

You have to remove the first "return".

Comment: Thanks guys:) But, like I said earlier, if I remove the 1st return statement and just write onClick='getClks(); postClocks();return false;' then, my getClks() function doesn't display the alerts as expected.

Comment: hmm, ok... what is the expected behaviour and what happens instead? I think the getClks should have the same behaviour, beacause the "return" has no effect on the code inside getClks.

Comment: Thankyou for helping, hacksteak25! :) I tried K Ivanov's suggestion and it works. My problem is solved :)